# Error after compiling "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am getting this error after compile my app the app is just frozen it worked before, but now it freezing and not loading. Code where it shows this error:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController");//(error is on this line)

[pool release];

return retVal;

}
```

Comment: See: https://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: The error was probably caused somewhere else. You should ad some NSlog along the path to identify what was the last instruction executed before crashing.

Comment: Are there any blue arrows on the left side of the code? If so, select them and try running your project again.

Comment: @CalebKleveter nope there isn't any blue arrows.